# IE -11 compatibility issue with <select> tag

Tags: html

I am facing an issue with a drop down `select` in IE11. If the drop down contains one `option` element it does not expand down while selecting options. The `option` is overlapping the `select` which makes it difficult to select.

**Example: I have a drop down which consists of element "Ajitesh"**

```
<select> <option> Ajitesh </option> </select>
```

In the above code whilst selecting "Ajitesh" the drop down is not expanding down .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to contain the single option in an `opt-group` tag like so:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="">
        <option value="Ajitesh">Ajitesh</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Otherwise, you could simply add an another - or many - empty option tags like:

```
<select>
    <option value="Ajitesh">Ajitesh</option>
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

*edit:* Please note that this is IE11 (and others) default behaviour, that is, it has been designed to prohibit the use of a dropdown with only one option. If you do not want to add an empty element, there isn't the option of changing the default behaviour of the browser itself - it's just not possible given your circumstances.

Comment: Thankx ..But our requirement says not to add any other empty element ..as above code is working fine in other browser . Only problem is with IE 11

Comment: Ajitesh, that's unfortunate, as this is IE 11's default behaviour, and you are unable to modify this particular behaviour - see my edit.